# Is backward compatibility for fingerprint sensor (< SDK 23) in android available?

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

My main application uses min SDK version 19. In my **onCreate()** I have checked whether the device supports fingerprint hardware or not. If the device supports fingerprint sensor then it will show the OS level fingerprint dialog else it will continue with the login screen.
I am unable to use the fingerprint helper class since it requires min SDK 23. Is there any backward compatibility available to achieve this scenario?
Examples and links would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can refer my sample code in my github  : https://github.com/rmkrishna/FingerPrint

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I have tried your code. It is working fine. Thank you for your help. Need a another small help. Is it possible to add the fingerprint dialog using fingerprint manager in this code?

Comment: yes, you can add a dialog and add the Finger print listener in that.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran can you please add the same in the above repo?

Comment: Sure tonight I will add.

Answer (score 0):

Use @TargetSdk(23) on top of the helperClass that generates the error.
Make sure to only call it once you have verified that the user has the appropriate hardware/software.